# CSS won't load because of the script given from the template

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I've been looking for the answer I seek in many posts before. But none of them worked for me.

I'm learning CI currently and want to implement it with admin panel template called Clip-Two. I will give brief explaination about my problem.

**Problem :** In some of my pages the CSS works fine, however in some of the pages the partially loaded.

Below is my controller called Users.php

**Users.php**

Within this controller, i have two functions, mainly the first one is for index, and the second one is when i want to create a user.

In the first function, the CSS works fine. All the required CSS files are loaded shown below.

**Index.php**
[image: Index.php]

However, in the second function, which have a new page, it only load partially of the whole CSS files.

**Create.php**
[image: Create.php]

Below is my header template

**header.php**

The one that I highlight is the CSS file that doesnt loaded properly.

When I inspect the elements, the file path is wrong, shown below.

**Elements**
[image: elements.php]

Below is my config file on base_url().

**Base_url()**

So, I'm confused, is it my base_url() went wrong or is it something else. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!.

Sorry I made a very long post, i just want everybody have a clear picture of my problem.

**EDITED**
I'm using admin template from Clip-Two
Below is the console error shown on my page.
Sorry I think my post is a bit misleading, I have edited my title and my problem

**Problem :** the jQuery from the template have the theme selector, so basically the jQuery could not find the path.

[image: console]

It shows that jQuery could not find the path.

Is this my problem lies on the jQuery?

Comment: Possible that this is a caching issue. Clear your cache / force reload / add a query string variable to the URL - and try again. You should also be able to replace the `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` with a simple `/` and load the `assets...` using a relative path. Edit: Can you load the `logo.png` directly?

Comment: Don't post images of code. Also make sure your assets out side of application folder

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you are not manipulating with that stylesheet using JavaScript? (You have an id identifier on  tag.)

Also, insted of `<?php echo base_url()?>`, try `<?=base_url()?>` it takes way less space.

Comment: i edited my post, it is shown jQuery could not find the path

Comment: Yes. It is looking in the wrong path. Instead of ../lookwaxy_admin/assets/.. it's searching in ../lookwaxy_admin/users..

Comment: Yeah,so does it mean i have to modify it? or is there a simpler solution to this?

Comment: Can you please show me the script, where the skin changer is located?

Comment: im not sure i could find the right js for the selector